# Juju - agent-state stuck on allocating

Tags: juju, maas

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, using the MaaS environment. The commands I used was:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju-core
wget -c https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.22.1-trusty-amd64.tgz
```

**On the ~/.juju/environments.yaml file:**

```
 maas:
        type: maas

        # maas-server specifies the location of the MAAS server. It must
        # specify the base path.
        #
        maas-server: 'http://172.16.1.160/MAAS/'

        # maas-oauth holds the OAuth credentials from MAAS.
        #
        maas-oauth: 'hf2bxnTtpCzKYqjTM2:NMuK7kFXrwsyqAvArK:ZbhT76BDbyMEU5mTXxv9X6YJuAPAMBcS'
        admin-secret: password
        agent-metadata-url: http://172.16.1.160/juju-metadata/tools
        # maas-server bootstrap ssh connection options
        #

        # bootstrap-timeout time to wait contacting a state server, in seconds.
        bootstrap-timeout: 1800
```

I ran these commands:

```
juju bootstrap
sudo apt-get install bzr
mkdir –p /opt/charms/trusty; cd /opt/charms/trusty
bzr branch lp:charms/wordpress
bzr branch lp:charms/mysql
bzr branch lp:charms/juju-gui
juju deploy --to 0 –-repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/juju-gui
juju deploy –-repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/wordpress
juju deploy –-repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/mysql
juju add-relation wordpress mysql
```

And after of all of this, I got the hook failed: install, so I did

```
juju debug-log
```

Have to get this package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:charmers/charm-helpers
```

Then everything got green, but still couldn't access wordpress public address, I removed the machines and the services. I repeated the process and now I get this situation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

*How do I solve this situation?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to login on the machines that are stuck in "allocating" and see what's going on. Try `juju ssh <unit-name>`, or just `juju ssh N` where "N" is the machine id.

Also, the `debug-log` command you used will by default only show the last few lines, like `tail(1)`. Try `juju debug-log --replay`, that will give you the full output. But I think your best bet is to login on those machines.

Comment: This is what I get - http://i.imgur.com/wq08TRQ.png

Comment: It's a network issue. Maybe you are behind a proxy.